# Unknown column 'Age' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a procedure for an update into a table but keep running into an "Unknown column 'Age' in 'field list'" error. I created an almost identical procedure just before this one, which is what has me so confused on why this is not working. Below is my procedure code, and the table layout.

### Code for procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure NewChild(IN FirstName varchar(50),
IN LastName varchar(50),
IN Age int(2),
IN Sex varchar(7),
IN UserID int(8),
IN Allg_Notes varchar(500)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Client (FirstName,LastName,Age,Sex,UserID,Allg_Notes)
values (FirstName,LastName,Age,Sex,UserID,Allg_Notes);
End;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

### Code for table

```
CREATE TABLE `Child` (
`ChildID` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`FirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`LastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`Age` int(2) NOT NULL,
`Sex` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
`UserID` int(8) NOT NULL,
`Allg_Notes` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ChildID`),
KEY `UserID` (`UserID`),
CONSTRAINT `Child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`) REFERENCES `Client`(`UserID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### Calling Example

```
Call NewChild('Jack','Person',2,'male',3,'none');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay
change this:

```
INSERT INTO Client (FirstName,LastName,Age,Sex,UserID,Allg_Notes)
```

To this

```
INSERT INTO Child (FirstName,LastName,Age,Sex,UserID,Allg_Notes)
```

Comment: *Facepalm* Thank you. This is what happens when I code on no sleep. Sorry to trouble those of you who read this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Field names as variables.

So instead of Field name mysql will use the inserted value

Comment: Forgive me for not understanding, but wouldn't that make the error be "Unknown column 2 in field list"? The reason this is so confusing to me is that I had literally just added a different procedure using the same syntax. Just different table and columns, and it worked without issue.